# Trigger a shift key press, when enter key is pressed - Jquery

Tags: jquery, keydown

I got this code in jquery -:

```
$('#postBoxEditor').live("keydown",function(e){ 
if(e.which == 13 && !e.shiftKey){ e.preventDefault(); 
var triggerevent = jQuery.Event("keydown"); triggerevent.which = 16; //shift key code
$(this).trigger(triggerevent); }             });
```

But this doesn't trigger a shift key press when enter is pressed, which is all i want.

Comment: `.live()` is deprecated use `.on()` instead.

Comment: Can you elaborate more what you are trying to do ? I can not understand the objective yet?

Answer (score 1):

the magic can just happen if you listen to an object that has this events
e.shiftKey is true if pressed, so you need to erase your '!'

```
top.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
   if(e.shiftKey) {
     /* do nice stuff.. */
   }
}, false);
```

same works with:
e.altKey; e.ctrlKey; e.metaKey;

your code should look like:

```
$('#postBoxEditor').on("keydown",function(e){
    if((e.keyCode == 13) && e.shiftKey) {
        e.preventDefault(); 
    }
});
```

hope thats it! :)

but what you want is.

```
<script>
var enterflag=false;
var shiftenterflag=false;
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#in').on('keydown',function(e){
        if(e.keyCode==13) enterflag=true;
        if(e.keyCode==16 && enterflag) {
            shiftenterflag=true;
            $('#report').show();
        }
    });
    $('#in').on('keyup',function(e){
        if(e.keyCode==16 && enterflag) $('#report').hide();
        if(e.keyCode==13) { 
            enterflag=false;
            shiftenterflag=false;
        }                
    });
});
</script>
<label>press enter and shift while focus in input to show the magic</label>
<input type="text" id="in" value="press enter and shift" style="with:200px" />
<div id="report" style="display:none">test</div>
```

this triggers enter+shift but not shift+enter

Comment: if you want to trigger shift after enter is pressed you need to save your enter-trigger in a var

Comment: Now how to save enter-trigger in a var.... What i need is, that when enter is pressed, it should trigger a enter+shift keypress.